# How to create a single field multiple image upload with two models?

Tags: django, image, upload

I have a model called Product that needs multiple image upload capabilities. I have thus created a separate model called Images to link back to Product with a ForeignKey relationship. I need some help to write a function that can loop over each uploaded image and create the foreign key relationship back to Product.

What follows is a simplified model:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.Charfield()
    description = models.TextField()
...
```

...and the Images model:

```py
class Images(model.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

Simple forms for them both (Images omitted but it's the same idea:

```py
class ProductCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

Also, the template includes `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to allow multiple upload selection.

I would like to know create a view function to loop over the uploads and create the ForeignKey relationship. Something like this:

```py
def CreateProduct(request):
    if request.method = 'POST'
```

... (now this is where I just have no idea how to write this. I'm very new to Django and programming/scripting in general.)

Comment: Take a look at formsets to upload multiple files at once: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: @hendrikschneider Thank you, that's what I'm looking for.